# Django - 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'post'

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to implement a likes functionality in a posts application (similar to Instagram posts), but when I submit the form for the like button, I keep getting this error saying that 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'post'.

The view code is as follows:

```
@login_required
def like_view(request, post_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=post_id)
        obj = ''
        try:
            obj = Like.objects.get(user=request.user, post=post)
            user_like = Like()
            user_like.user = request.user
            user_like.post = post
            post.likes += 1
            user_like.save()
            post.save()
            context = {'post' : post, 'post_id' : post_id}
            return render(request, context=context)
        except Like.DoesNotExist:
            user_like = Like()
            user_like.user = request.user
            user_like.post = post
            post.likes += 1
            user_like.save()
            post.save()
            context = {'post' : post, 'post_id' : post_id}
            return render(request, context=context)
    else:
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=post_id)
        context = {'post' : post, 'post_id' : post_id}
        return render(request, context=context)
```

Here's the template:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-12 bg-dark text-light mb-3 p-0">
<div class="media pt-3 pl-3 bg-dark text-light">
    <a href="{% url 'users:detail' post.user.username %}">
        <img src="{{ post.profile.picture.url }}" alt="{{ post.user.get_full_name }}" style="height: 35px; width: 35px;" class="mr-3 rounded-circle">
    </a>
    <div class="media-body">
        <p style="margin-top: 5px;">{{ post.user.username }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
<img src="{{ post.photo.url }}" alt="{{ post.title }}" class="img-fluid mt-2">
<p class="mt-3 ml-3">
    <a href="#" class="heart-icon" style="font-size: 20px;" onclick="document.getElementById('likeButton').submit()">
        <i class="far fa-heart"></i>
    </a><a href="" class="ml-1 likes-link text-light" style="text-decoration: none;">30 likes</a>
</p>
<form action="{% url 'posts:like' post.pk %}" id="likeButton" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" value="{{ post }}">
</form>
<hr>
<p class="ml-3 mt-0 mb-3">
    <b>{{ post.title }}</b> - <small>{{ post.created }}</small>
</p>
{% if post.description %}
<hr>
<p class="ml-3 mt-2">{{ post.description }}</p>
{% endif %}
```

Apparently it's telling me that I'm not sending any 'post' object in the request, so I want to know why isn't it sending it in the context, and how can I fix this.

Comment: Can you show the full error trace? It's not clear on which line of your code this error is thrown.

Comment: Note your last `else` statement is indented incorrectly, as it's probably intended to cover the "GET" case.

Comment: It is because of SO's text editor. In the code it is indented correctly. @dirkgroten

Comment: Well fix it then so your question is correct. But please, add the full error trace.